# Wordpress - add a new product

Tags: php, wordpress

On the web page there are some products, like this.

```
 <div class-"products-list"> 
        <div class="product>
          <h2> Title </h2>
          <span> Description</span>
          <span> Price </span>
          <button> Buy </button>
        </div>
 </div>
```

How can I make available for a customer to use the WP admin panel and add this **div class="product** manually with possiblity **to edit h2 / description / price without going into the code?**
I know the plugin "Advanced fields", but it enables only editing existing texts/imgs and so on, but not creating the copies of existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you are editing the pages you are in "Visual" mode. Change it to "Text" by clicking the Text tab in top right corner of the page editing window. Then add the necessary element where you want in the html document.